# Unable to cast object of type 'RSACng' to type 'System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider'

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, google-authentication

I got this exception:

> Unable to cast object of type 'RSACng' to type 'System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider'

calling this method:

```
GoogleCredential cred = GoogleCredential.FromFile(path);
```

Full exception:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'RSACng' to type 'System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider'
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer.FromPrivateKey(String privateKey) in C:\Apiary\2019-09-11.10-11-15\Src\Support\Google.Apis.Auth\OAuth2\ServiceAccountCredential.cs:line 110
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.CreateServiceAccountCredentialFromParameters(JsonCredentialParameters credentialParameters) in C:\Apiary\2019-09-11.10-11-15\Src\Support\Google.Apis.Auth\OAuth2\DefaultCredentialProvider.cs:line 243
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.CreateDefaultCredentialFromParameters(JsonCredentialParameters credentialParameters) in C:\Apiary\2019-09-11.10-11-15\Src\Support\Google.Apis.Auth\OAuth2\DefaultCredentialProvider.cs:line 197
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleCredential.FromFile(String path) in C:\Apiary\2019-09-11.10-11-15\Src\Support\Google.Apis.Auth\OAuth2\GoogleCredential.cs:line 114
   at ServerUtil.GCloudReporter..ctor(String version, String deployEnv)
```

Using .NET Framework 4.5.1

Google apis libs version 1.41.1

Comment: Looking at https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/Src/Support/Google.Apis.Auth/OAuth2/ServiceAccountCredential.cs this code tries to cast result of RSA.Create() method to RSACryptoServiceProvider. Factory methods of class RSA can be overridden by machine.config and also default can differ for different .NET runtimes, for details can look here https://dusted.codes/how-to-use-rsa-in-dotnet-rsacryptoserviceprovider-vs-rsacng-and-good-practise-patterns. Probably nobody tested this very deep :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was that app was running in .NET Core environment, but this specific code was in project setup for .NET Framework. Moving code to project with .NET Core setup fix problem.

Comment: @Yuri You said the problem was that the app was running in .NET core and then you moved the code to a .net core project.  Confused, it was there already.  You figured it out so please share with community.

Answer (score 4):

I was getting exactly the same exception.

In my case I was using Sustainsys.Saml2.AspNetCore2 version (2.8.0) nuget package.

I've updated to 2.9.0 and delete all cookies related to authentication.

It solved my problem.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31309295)

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had this error when wanted to use my notification service from the service layer into my .NetCore project.

> Unable to cast object of type 'RSACng' to type 'System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider'

I only added "FirebaseAdmin" package to my .NetCore project using package manager.

it was confusing for me because I did not get this error on my .Net Framework project which does not need this package.

pretty silly mistake but I hope this saves others valuable time

Answer (score 0):

**.NET core**
Step1: insall System.Security.Cryptography.Cng from nuget pkg
Step2:create a class "X509Certificate2Signature"

```
    using iTextSharp.text.pdf.security;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;

namespace DigiSignNETCORE
{
    public class X509Certificate2Signature : IExternalSignature
    {
        private String hashAlgorithm;
        private String encryptionAlgorithm;
        private X509Certificate2 certificate;

        public X509Certificate2Signature(X509Certificate2 certificate, String hashAlgorithm)
        {
            if (!certificate.HasPrivateKey)
                throw new ArgumentException("No private key.");
            this.certificate = certificate;
            this.hashAlgorithm = DigestAlgorithms.GetDigest(DigestAlgorithms.GetAllowedDigests(hashAlgorithm));
            if (certificate.PrivateKey is RSACryptoServiceProvider)
                encryptionAlgorithm = "RSA";
            else if (certificate.PrivateKey is DSACryptoServiceProvider)
                encryptionAlgorithm = "DSA";
            
            else if (certificate.PrivateKey is System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng)
                encryptionAlgorithm = "RSA";
        }

        public virtual byte[] Sign(byte[] message)
        {
            if (certificate.PrivateKey is RSACryptoServiceProvider)
            {
                RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)certificate.PrivateKey;
                return rsa.SignData(message, hashAlgorithm);
            }
           else if (certificate.PrivateKey is System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng)
            {
                System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng rSACng = (System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng)certificate.PrivateKey;
                return rSACng.SignData(message,HashAlgorithmName.SHA1,RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
            }

            else
            {
                DSACryptoServiceProvider dsa = (DSACryptoServiceProvider)certificate.PrivateKey;
                return dsa.SignData(message);
            }
        }

        public virtual String GetHashAlgorithm()
        {
            return hashAlgorithm;
        }

        public virtual String GetEncryptionAlgorithm()
        {
            return encryptionAlgorithm;
        }
    }
}
```

step 3 : in this line IExternalSignature externalSignature = new X509Certificate2Signature(cert, "SHA1"); point the class "X509Certificate2Signature" which you created recenlty.

Answer (score 0):

This example uses variables for a specific certificate in the local computer store and the string that should be encrypted/decrypted using Cryptography API: Next Generation (CNG).

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;

namespace X509CertEncrypt
{
    class Program
    {
        // Variables 
        public static string certificateName = "localhost";
        public static string sSecret = "TextToEncrypt";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();

            // Get the certificate 
            p.getCertificate(certificateName);

            // Encryption 
            string sEncryptedSecret = string.Empty;
            sEncryptedSecret = p.EncryptRsa(sSecret);

            // Decryption 
            string sDecryptedSecret = string.Empty;
            sDecryptedSecret = p.decryptRsa(sEncryptedSecret);

            ////Display the original data and the decrypted data.
            Console.WriteLine("Original:   {0}", sSecret);
            Console.WriteLine("Encypted Value:   {0}", sEncryptedSecret);
            Console.WriteLine("Round Trip: {0}", sDecryptedSecret);
            Console.WriteLine("Press the Enter key to exit.");
        }

        private X509Certificate2 getCertificate(string certificateName)
        {
            X509Store my = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
            my.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

            X509Certificate2Collection collection = my.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, certificateName, false);
            if (collection.Count == 1)
            {
                return collection[0];
            }
            else if (collection.Count > 1)
            {
                throw new Exception(string.Format("More than one certificate with name '{0}' found in store LocalMachine/My.", certificateName));
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception(string.Format("Certificate '{0}' not found in store LocalMachine/My.", certificateName));
            }
        }

        private string EncryptRsa(string input)
        {
            string output = string.Empty;
            X509Certificate2 cert = getCertificate(certificateName);

            // Changed from 
            //      using (RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PublicKey.Key)
            // to
            //      using (System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng csp = (System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng)cert.PublicKey.Key)
            // because of 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng' to type 'System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider'.'

            // Changed from 
            //      byte[] bytesEncrypted = csp.Encrypt(bytesData, false);
            // To            
            //      byte[] bytesEncrypted = csp.Encrypt(bytesData, System.Security.Cryptography.RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA512);

            using (System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng csp = (System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng)cert.PublicKey.Key)
            {
                byte[] bytesData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
                //byte[] bytesEncrypted = csp.Encrypt(bytesData, false);
                byte[] bytesEncrypted = csp.Encrypt(bytesData, System.Security.Cryptography.RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA512);
                output = Convert.ToBase64String(bytesEncrypted);
            }
            return output;
        }

        private string decryptRsa(string encrypted)
        {
            string text = string.Empty;
            X509Certificate2 cert = getCertificate(certificateName);
            // using (RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey)
            using (System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng csp = (System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng)cert.PrivateKey)
            {
                byte[] bytesEncrypted = Convert.FromBase64String(encrypted);
                byte[] bytesDecrypted = csp.Decrypt(bytesEncrypted, System.Security.Cryptography.RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA512);
                text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesDecrypted);
            }
            return text;
        }
    }
}
```