# PowerShell authenticate and read google calendar events

Tags: powershell

Using PowerShell, I am trying to authenticate to Google calendar using a service account, and read events. With the help of [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75254444/cannot-import-google-calendar-api-library-to-powershell/75291334), I was able to install and import the required packages in my PowerShell session.

- Newtonsoft.Json
- Google.Apis.Core
- Google.Apis
- Google.Apis.Auth
- Google.Apis.Calendar.v3

I then tried to read Google calendar events

```
# Set the credentials and calendar ID
$credentials = Get-Content "C:\Users\Windows\Desktop\powershell-376318-70973daa61d9.json" | ConvertFrom-Json
$calendarId = "primary"

# Build the calendar service
$service = New-Object Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.CalendarService
$service.Credentials = New-Object Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleCredential($credentials)

# Get the current time
$now = Get-Date

# Get the events for the next hour
$events = $service.Events.List($calendarId)
$events.TimeMin = $now
$events.TimeMax = $now.AddHours(1)
$events.SingleEvents = $true
$events.OrderBy = "startTime"
$events = $events.Execute()

# Print the events
foreach ($event in $events.Items) {
    Write-Host "Event: $($event.Summary)"
    Write-Host "Start Time: $($event.Start.DateTime)"
    Write-Host "End Time: $($event.End.DateTime)"
    Write-Host ""
}
```

But I get this error

```
New-Object : A constructor was not found. Cannot find an appropriate constructor for type 
Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleCredential.
At line:7 char:24
+ ... edentials = New-Object Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleCredential($cred ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotFindAppropriateCtor,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
 
Exception calling "Execute" with "0" argument(s): "The service calendar has thrown an exception. HttpStatusCode is 
Forbidden. The request is missing a valid API key."
At line:18 char:1
+ $events = $events.Execute()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GoogleApiException
```

Obviously, there's an issue with "Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleCredential". I'm not sure it's even possible to authenticate and read events using a service account, but right now I don't know how to proceed with this.

I want to avoid using OAuth2 client id and client secret for authentication if possible, because I've had issues in the past with token expiries, whereas a service account doesn't expire.

Comment: Read following : https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-api-client/latest/com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential  Your are using a deprecated method with OAuth2

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you exactly what the problem is:

```
Cannot find an appropriate constructor for type Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleCredential.
```

Having a look at the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Apis/latest/Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleCredential) shows: There really is no constructor like `GoogleCredential(string)`. But you can use different static methods to create a `GoogleCredential` object. E. g. [`FromJson(String)`](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Apis/latest/Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleCredential#Google_Apis_Auth_OAuth2_GoogleCredential_FromJson_System_String_):

```
# Set the credentials and calendar ID
$credentials = Get-Content -Raw -Path "C:\Users\Windows\Desktop\powershell-376318-70973daa61d9.json"

# Build the calendar service
$service = New-Object Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.CalendarService
$service.Credentials = [Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleCredential]::FromJson($credentials)
```

---

You can also pass the file directly to `GoogleCredential` via [`FromFile`](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Apis/latest/Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleCredential#Google_Apis_Auth_OAuth2_GoogleCredential_FromFile_System_String_):

```
# Build the calendar service
$service = New-Object Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.CalendarService
$service.Credentials = [Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleCredential]::FromFile('C:\Users\Windows\Desktop\powershell-376318-70973daa61d9.json')
```

Comment: this gives me an error: "MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "FromJson" with "1" argument(s): "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Security.Cryptography.RSAWrapper' to type 'System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider'.""

Comment: Well, you have to provide the expected JSON, of course. I highly recommend to read the docs. There are a lot of functions and the docs tell you what input format they expect. Please check out [this link](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Apis/latest/Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleCredential#Google_Apis_Auth_OAuth2_GoogleCredential_FromFile_System_String_) and have a look at **all** following `From*` functions. Unless you share your sanitized JSON file, we can only make guesses here...

Comment: this is a modified version of the json file provided by google when creating a service account 

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "po",
  "private_key_id": "",
  "private_key": "",
  "client_email": "",
  "client_id": "",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/powershell2%40powershell-376318.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. It should work with that. So I think you are facing [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58342269/11942268) now.

Comment: The first suggestion was to install "Sustainsys.Saml2.AspNetCore2" which I did, but still got the same error. Then the answer was to move the project from .net core to .net framework. But I don't know how to do that in powershell.

Comment: This is out of scope of your question here. Please ask for clarification in the linked question or post a new question with your exact error message.

Comment: as I said in the question, I need to authenticate and read events. so the answer is not complete.